# What about problems with loading native library/missing methods: libttJdbc.so, libtten.so

Tags: timesten

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: /home/timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbc.so: libtten.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1794)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:305)
    at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:161)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Thankyou

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/653235 - it seems that libttJdbc.so has not been found/failed to be opened

Answer (score 2):

Code Example:

```
try{        
     String driverName =  "com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenClientDriver"; // "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
      String Url = "jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=timestendb_1122"; //"jdbc:odbc:timestendb_1122";   

       if(args.length >= 2){
                 driverName = args[0]; 
                 Url = args[1];
        }           

        System.out.println("driverName=" + driverName);
        System.out.println("Url=" + Url);
        System.out.println("classPath=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));     

            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

              // Open a connection to TimesTen
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Url);        

            if(conn != null){
                System.out.println("okay");
            }
            else{
                 System.out.println("fail");
            }
                conn.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

odbc.ini config:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
timestendb_11221=TimesTen 11.2.2 Driver

[timestendb_1122]
TTC_SERVER=(Host || IP)
UID=Username
PWD=Password
TTC_SERVER_DSN=Cachedb01
```

> Error: java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native
>   library/missing methods: /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbcCS.so:
>   libttclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Resolve:

Check if exists:

```
$ldd /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbcCS.so
```

Screen:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff039b4000)
    libttclient.so => not found
    libttco.so => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f57d642e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f57d6218000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f57d5e58000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f57d5c53000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f57d6876000)
```

Check directory timesten client: `$ ll /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttclient.so`

Go to to file to add share lib : `sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/extension.conf`  -> Add:  `/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib`

Check Again

```
java -Djava.library.path=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib -jar test1.jar
```

Code Print:

```
driverName=com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenClientDriver
Url=jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=timestendb_1122
classPath=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib
java.sql.SQLException: [TimesTen][TimesTen 11.2.2.5.0 CLIENT]Cannot find the requested DSN (timestendb_1122) in ODBCINI, Unable to open /var/TimesTen/tt1122/sys.odbc.ini. Permission denied
```

Resolve:

1. `export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini` (if you used odbc driver)
2. `export ODBCINI=/var/TimesTen/tt1122/sys.odbc.ini` (if used timesten driver)

Can be add  bash file for user:

```
nano /home/nhatvd/.bashrc 
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini

$ ldd /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbcCS.so

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff429fe000)
    libttclient.so => /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttclient.so (0x00007fd7977ee000)
    libttco.so => /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttco.so (0x00007fd797520000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd797223000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd79700d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd796c4d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd796a48000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd796748000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd79652b000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fd796310000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd797b12000)
```

Result:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib -jar test1.jar
```

Code Print:

```
driverName=com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenClientDriver
Url=jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=timestendb_1122
classPath=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib
```

okay

DONE.